# Julia 1.0.0 on Windows 10 error from 'using PyPlot': "The Python package matplotlib could not be found by pyimport. "

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, julia

Just installed Julia 1.0.0 from julialang.org
Did the following:

```
using Pkg
```

Pkg.add("PyPlot")
using PyPlot

. . .  got this error:
The Python package matplotlib could not be found by pyimport. Usually this means that you did not install matplotlib in the Python version being used by PyCall.

I have installed anaconda.

HERE IS FULL JULIA 1.0.0 LOG...………

```
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  Documentation: https://docs.julialang.org
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?" for help, "]?" for Pkg help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 1.0.0 (2018-08-08)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official https://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |

julia> using Pkg

julia> Pkg.add("PyPlot")
  Updating registry at `C:\Users\douglaskbell\.julia\registries\General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
 Resolving package versions...
  Updating `C:\Users\douglaskbell\.julia\environments\v1.0\Project.toml`
 [no changes]
  Updating `C:\Users\douglaskbell\.julia\environments\v1.0\Manifest.toml`
 [no changes]

julia> using PyPlot
[ Info: Installing matplotlib via the Conda matplotlib package...
[ Info: Running `conda install -y matplotlib` in root environment
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

ERROR: InitError: PyError (PyImport_ImportModule

The Python package matplotlib could not be found by pyimport. Usually this means
that you did not install matplotlib in the Python version being used by PyCall.
```

Comment: Do you try to use a global python installation or let Julia install a python version for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help (setting the right path to the anaconda python binary)?

```
ENV["PYTHON"] = "c:\\full\\path\\to\\anaconda\\bin\\python"
using Pkg
Pkg.build("PyCall")
using PyPlot
```

Comment: Alas, it still doesn't plot.  using PyPlot gets error compiling because can't load library: julia\\packages\\Conda\\m7vem\\deps\\usr\\python37\   And I opened this StackO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228402/julia-1-0-0-on-windows-10-could-not-load-library-expected-at-julia-packages-c