# Julia 1.0.0 on Windows 10 using PyPlot compiler error because it can't load library expected at: .julia\\packages\\Conda\\m7vem\\deps\\usr\\python37\

Tags: windows, matplotlib, julia

I'm trying to get matplotlib working with Julia 1.0.0.
Installed it but get error when I try to test it by doing this...

```
ENV["PYTHON"]="c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe"
using Pkg
Pkg.add("PyPlot")
using PyPlot
```

...which gets this error:

```
ErrorException("error compiling display_error: error compiling findprev: error compiling lookup: error compiling Type: could not load library \"C:\\Users\\ME\\.julia\\packages\\Conda\\m7vem\\deps\\usr\\python37\"\nThe specified module could not be found.\r\n")
```

Here is what I have at: .julia\packages\Conda\m7vem\deps\usr\

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to configure an external Python with Julia do the following steps.

```
ENV["PYTHON"]="c:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe"
```

Now press `]` and in the `(v1.0) pkg>` prompt type:

```
build PyCall
build PyPlot
```

Now press backspace to return to the normal REPL.

I suppose you installed `PyCall` before setting the Python path. Python path change requires a package rebuild.